# Subclassing UICollectionReusableView

Tags: ios6

I've been trying to subclass UICollectionReusableView in a non-storyboard iPad project. I've built a view in IB and hooked it up to my custom class, registered the class for reuse in the viewController where my collection view lives, and am calling it correctly in

```
UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

However, nothing shows up in my header areas in the UICollectionView. I think I need too init the view with coder, but am unsure how to do that correctly. I followed a couple of examples I found, but the header view still does not appear in my collection view.

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CVHeaderView" owner:self options:nil];
    [self addSubview:self.categoryNameLabel];
}
return self;
```

}

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use a storyboard and select the header/footer checkmark `initWithCoder:` will be called.

If you do not use the storyboard (or do not click header/footer) but hook it up manually you have to register your custom classes and `initWithFrame:` will be called.

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[GameCardCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"GameCardCell"];
[self.collectionView registerClass:[PlayerHeaderView class] forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"PlayerHeaderView"];
[self.collectionView registerClass:[PlayerFooterView class] forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter withReuseIdentifier:@"PlayerFooterView"];
```

Note: Both will be called only once. If the view comes out of the cache `prepareForReuse` will be called.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, `initWithFrame:` is called automatically when dequeueing it for the first time. Try to implement this method and see if it works.